# C# Serialize WinForm

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, serialization

I am trying to serialize a winform, with the end goal of being able to recreate the values in the various controls of the form. My form contains the typical controls, buttons/radio buttons/checkboxes/textboxes/listbox/tab control.

I am receiving this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred 
in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There was an error reflecting type 
'Receptionist_Program.Objects.Client.Client_NCQ'.
```

I setup properties for each value I want to save:

```
    public bool CbMedTreat
    {
        get { return cbMedTreat.Checked; }
        set { cbMedTreat.Checked = value; }
    }

    public List<Client_AddDoctor> TxtDocExplain // Client_AddDoctor is another form
    {
        get { return listDoctors; }
        set { listDoctors = value; }
    }
    // etc, variety of string and bool properties
```

At the top of the class I have the decoration:

```
    [Serializable]
    public partial class Client_NCQ : Form
```

Finally, here is my code doing the serialization:

```
            Client_NCQ badname = new Client_NCQ();
        badname.Initialize();
        badname.ShowDialog();

        string result = "";

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Client_NCQ));
        // Error occurs here on above line: new XmlSerializer(typeof(Client_NCQ))
        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, badname);
            result = textWriter.ToString();
        }
```

I tried two different things so far, first, I added the decoration [XmlIgnore] to the List<> property, this made no difference. Second, I tried ensuring that the constructor was empty and had no parameters.

Comment: What's your `InnerException`? It should give you details about what property it has problems with. I'm betting on `Site` if you have non-visual components on the form

Comment: First level: `{"Cannot serialize member 'System.ComponentModel.Component.Site' of type 'System.ComponentModel.ISite', see inner exception for more details."}`. Inside that exception, is one last inner exception: `{"Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.Component.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface."}`

Comment: Yeah, I won my bet! :-) I don't think you can serialize the form as it is, since it has some components that are not serializable. You'll need to separate your data from the form, and serialize the data only

Comment: That makes sense, I'll create a separate object and use it to populate the form. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serializing an entire `Form` is a bad idea because it is not meant to be serialized:

- it has a lot of properties that should not be serialized (e.g. displaying related properties)
- even if it works properly, you will have a lot of data that is not relevant for your application's state

The correct solution is to keep all state information in your custom objects and bind to those objects using WinForm's [databinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx) capabilities. If this means great changes to your application, try to serialize only the data that is relevant to constructing the state.

How can you know which data is relevant for application state?

Before constructing and showing the form, I expect that you are loading the data from a database, file etc. All that information should be contained in clearly defined objects of types marked with `[Serializable]` attribute. This way, it is easy to serialize and deserialize it at will.

Also, it is important to take into consideration [version tolerant serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.100).aspx) or what happens when the form / state information is changed (e.g. a field is added) and an older XML is used to restore state.

Comment: Thank you Alexei. I will get started researching the databinding capabilities

Comment: Even without databinding (it takes some time getting used to using it and of course, changing the code in lots of places), you must have a clear separation between your application data (model) and view (UI). This also allows for easier changes in one layer with minimum impact upon the other (e.g.use a custom data picker instead of the standard one)

Comment: @Alexei - Good answer.

Comment: @BrianCombs - You can ignore databinding an just do simple assignment to and from your data object if that makes it easier. Databinding would be the way to go, but it can introduce other complexities.

Comment: @Enigmativity That is what I ended up doing. Custom class to store my data, filled from in the constructor and assigned to in the FormClosing event. So I serialize and deserialize the class and just pass it to a new instance of the form and retrieve the updated version from the form when the user closes the form.

Answer (score 0):

Every form has its own mechanism to store and retrieve (serialize and deserialize) data and it does this automatically. However, the following conditions are to be met in order to use this feature automatically.

```
-  All properties which are desired to be serialized must have public get and set accesor.
 - If a certain property represents custom object such as user defined class or struct, the object must be adorned with [Serializable] attribute.
 - Property which is desired to be serialized must not have [DesignerSerializationVisibility] attribute set to Hidden. By default it is Visible so not specifying this attribute at all is sufficiently serves the purpose.
```

Consider this example:

```
namespace MnM.Drawing
{
    [Serializable, TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public class Coordinates
    {
        public int X { get; set; }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public int Z { get; protected set; }
    }

    public class MyForm : Form
    {

        [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        public Coordinates MyCoordinates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, MyForm will automatically serialize MyCoordinates object but...

- Only property X will get serialized because it fits the requisite
  status to qualify for auto serialization.
- Property Y can not be serialized because of DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)
- Property Z can not get serialized automatically because it does
  not have public set accesor.

In order to serialize Y and Z, custom serialization code is required. In most cases, need of custom serialization does not arise and custom serialization can be done in many ways but its a vast topic.

Comment: Not that I am complaining but it can be helpful to know my mistake led to downvoting so that I can rectify it. One can not find fault in his own logic and understanding. I request whoever downvoted my answer to at-least provide brief comment on what is wrong with answer.

Comment: The problem is that you are talking about "code serialization" (how the designer serializes the properties to code), and the question is totally different, it's asking about Xml Serialization of a form generated class (which is for the most part, not doable, as the accepted answer and my initial comments hints).

Comment: I appreciate you took time to explain. My intention was to throw light at a broader point. And that point being need of custom serialization. Why do we need it in first place? Why to complicate things when framework already is capable to accomplish what you want. Anyway I tend to agree that maybe my approach could have been different. I hope to learn more. Thanks a lot for your reply.